# C++ template argument of template argument

Tags: c++, templates

Look at this code:

```
template<class T, class Compare>
void foo(const std::set<T, Compare> & bar)
{
    // here I need the comparative function BUT with another type
    // like this:
    if (Compare<float>()(...))
}
```

Something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
template<class T, class Compare>
void foo(const std::set<T, Compare<T>> & bar)
...
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a template template parameter:

```
template<class T, template<class> class Compare>
```

Now the `Compare` template parameter is a template itself.